# Java SWT: Undoing actions performed when checkbox is unselected

Tags: java, for-loop, checkbox, swt

I have two check boxes that are setup to function like radio buttons (I used check boxes so that they could both default to `.setSelection(false)`) that when selected, they initiate a for loop that populates 4 composites with applicable check boxes. My issue is that I cannot find a way to either empty the composites or undo the actions performed when the buttons are unselected.

```
    final Button button = new Button(headerGroup, SWT.CHECK);
    button.setText("Label");

    Group group = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    group.setText("Group 2");
    group.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    GridData groupData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    groupData.heightHint = 100;
    groupData.widthHint = 150;
    group.setLayoutData(groupData);

    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(group, SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite .setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    scrolledComposite .setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Composite composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    composite .setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    composite .setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0){

            boolean valueButton;
            balueButton = button.getSelection(); 

            if(valueButton == true){

                List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
                String labels[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
                // This is the for loop that I want to undo/delete when
                // button is deselected
                for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    Button buttonLoop = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
                    buttonLoop.setText(labels[i]);
                    buttons.add(buttonLoop);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to reinitialize `composite` without the check boxes from the for loop upon deselection of `button`?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dispose of the Button controls you no longer want.

You can do this just be looking at the children of the Composite:

```
Control [] children = composite.getChildren();

for (Control child : children) {
  if (child instanceof Button && !child.isDisposed()) {
    child.dispose();
  }
}
```

You may also need to call `composite.layout(true)` to update the layout.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! `composite.layout(true)` wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose the widget in order to free the memory. Then you can create the composite as you did before:

```
composite.dispose();
composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I wasn't able to get it to work this way, however (I'm sure it is an error on my part).